# IdentityServer BestPractive Combine Implicit and RessourceOwner Workflow

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth, openid, identityserver3

**Given:**
A **Identity Server** which supports implicit and Resource Owner flow. (Config see below)

An **Api** that uses IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication. So it basiucally trades a password for a token which is used for auth

A **UI** which uses implicit workflow for auth.

Now I'm able to get a bearer token from the identity server with which I can access the protected api method.

Also as a User I'm able to log in with the implicit flow and see protected views.

**Problem**
The Problems comes when a signed in WebFrontEndUser wants to access a protected API.

The User signs in in the ui with the implicit flow. After he is authenticated he tries to access a protected api. 
The Api returns that he is not authorized.

How can I configure the environment so that the api uses the openid information from the user cookie?

**Website Confing**

```
   app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = "foo_implicit",
                Authority = identServer,
                RedirectUri = "http://localhost/foo/",
                ResponseType = "token id_token",
                Scope = "openid profile",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie
            });
```

**WebApi Config**

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            Authority = identServer
        });
```

**IdentityServer Client Config**

```
  new Client
                {
                    Enabled = true,
                    ClientId = "foo_implicit",
                    ClientName = "foo Site",
                    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                    {
                        new Secret("foo".Sha256())
                    },
                    Flow = Flows.Implicit,
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        Constants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        Constants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        "read"
                    },
                    RedirectUris = new List<string>()
                    {
                        "http://localhost/foo/"
                    }
                },
                new Client
                {
                    Enabled = true,
                    ClientId = "foo",
                    ClientName = "foo api",
                    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                    {
                        new Secret("foo".Sha256())
                    },
                    Flow = Flows.ResourceOwner,
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        Constants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        "read"
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using OpenID Connect you can request both Identity and Access Tokens during authentication. You are already getting an access token during authentication (response type `token`), so I would grab this and use it to access then API. This would prevent the need for a separate Resource Owner client.

You can grab this access token using the the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications` property of `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions`, e.g.:

```
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
{
    SecurityTokenValidated = x =>
    {
        x.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", x.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Also your `IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions` should state one or more Scopes that a token requires for access. Otherwise any access token from that authority can access your API. See [documentation](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/consuming/overview.html) for more details on this.

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = identServer,
    RequiredScopes = new[] { "api1" }
});
```